# how to convert a number to base32 in java as per RFC-4648

Tags: java, decode, base32, totp

Actually I'm trying to use TOTP in my app and google authenticator requires the key to be in base32 format. This is the reason I'm trying to convert a key to base32 format

Let's say I have a number = 150820200825235.

[This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base32#RFC_4648_Base32_alphabet) wikipedia page says that [RFC-4648](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4648) is the most common base32 alphabet used.

Here's my java code where I'm trying to convert a number to base 32:

```
    long key=150820200825235L;
    String base32Key = Long.toString(key,32);
    System.out.println(base32Key);
```

Now it is printing this as the output :

> 495e87tgcj

It contains 9 which is invalid according to RFC-4648.

how do I convert to base32 number as per RFC-4648 in java?

One more thing If the most widely used Base32 alphabet is really as per RFC-4648 then why doesn't java support it as default? or is something is wrong in my understanding/code ?

Comment: The word "base" is being used in 2 different contexts here: (1) the encoding scheme known as "base 32" for converting binary data to text; and (2) Taking a number and converting it to the equivalent number in a different "base" (more precisely, a different _radix_). In `Long.toString(key,32)`, the `32` is a radix. The English language can be a slippery eel.

Answer (score 1):

"Base32" as defined in RFC-4648 is a way to encode binary data ("arbitrary sequences of octets") in ASCII text using only numbers, upper case letters, and `=` for padding. You can find an implementation in the [Apache Commons Codec library](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base32.html)

If you start with a number like `150820200825235` and want to convert it into RFC 4648 base32, first you need to decide how to convert the number into a sequence of bytes.

**Foe example**, One way to convert a `long` value into bytes is using the `DataOutputStream.writeLong` method. This method uses 8 bytes. Using this method to write 150820200825235L and encoding the resulting bytes in base32 gives you `AAAISK4QP3AZG===`.